# jQuery wrap each array items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I try to wrap each array item inside a `<li></li>` and save into a variable.
After that insert a `<ul>` at the beginning and a `</ul>` at the end.

What I've got so far:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

  jQuery.each(array, function(index, value) {
    value[index].wrap("<li></li>");
    var listItems = value[index].join("\n");
  });
});
```

But I get this error:

```
value[index].wrap is not a function
```

Comment: You're trying to use a jQuery method on a plain JavaScript object instead of a jQuery object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/vkq3hnzu/2/

```
var array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],
  ul = $('<ul>');
jQuery.each(array, function(index, value) {
  $('<li>').text(value).appendTo(ul);
});
ul.appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Please use stack snippets instead of jsfiddle when feasible, to keep everything local.

Comment: I didn't realize such a thing existed; thanks for the heads-up.